# Python: How to unshadow the keyword 'property'?

Tags: python

I am supporting a **legacy** python application which has a class written as such (still running in python 2.4):

```
class MyClass(object):

    def property(self, property_code, default):
        ...
```

Now I am adding some new code to it:

```
    def _check_ok(self):
        ...

    ok = property(lamdba self:self._check_ok())
```

Basically I want to add a property **'ok'** to this class.

However it does not work. I encountered this error message:

```
TypeError: property() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

The existing class method 'property' has overshadowed the built-in 'property' keyword.

Is there any way I can use **'property'** the way it meant to be in my new code?

Refactor the existing `property()` function is not an option.

**EDIT:** If I put the new code before the `MyClass::property` def, it will work. But I really want to see if there is a better solution

**EDIT 2:** These codes work in shell

```
>>> class Jack(object):
...   def property(self, a, b, c):
...      return 2
...   p = __builtins__.property(lambda self: 1)
...
>>> a = Jack()
>>> a.p
1
>>> a.property(1, 2, 3)
2
```

But the same technique does not work in my app. Got **AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'property'** error

Comment: You used __builtins__, what happens when you use __builtin__ as Thomas K suggested?

Comment: Couldn't you just have `ok = property(_check_ok)`? Or use a decorator (`@property` above the `_check_ok` def)? Depending on your solution, you may have to more fully qualify `property` of course.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Python 2:

```
import __builtin__
__builtin__.property
```

Python 3:

```
import builtins
builtins.property
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas, it works. Just do not understand why \_\_builtins\_\_.property in shell works...

Comment: Short version: it's a messy part of Python, as `__builtins__` can be either a dict or a module. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184016/why-builtins-both-module-and-dict and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2173425/two-conflicting-meanings-of-builtins-in-python-3-python-3-1-python-3k-python30/2173457#2173457

Comment: And in case its relevant to anyone: In Python 3, you do `import builtins` (plural, no underscores), rather than `import __builtin__`.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
__builtins__.property(lamdba self:self._check_ok())
```

Comment: Get this error: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'property'. But if I tried your in the shell, it works.

Comment: sorry - I tested at the prompt. In a script you 'import __builtin__' and do __builtin__.property like Thomas K said.